# Hard drives seemingly no longer has bad sectors on it after erase and reformat

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

I have a Seagate SSHD laptop hard drive. When I use Seagates Software SeaTools. The drive used to fail the short drive self-tests and the long generic test. When it failed tests sea tools would warn me about having bad sectors. It would however to pass the short generic tests. I could access the data on the drive without any problems. I ran these tests from two different computers both from inside Windows 7 and Windows 10 and using sea tool for dos. When I try to run fix-all fast and fix-all long on the drive to try and fix the bad sectors it fails. All of a sudden after I deleted all the partitions on the drive and reformatted the drive after backing up the data on the drive. I just did a quick format too. Now the drive somehow can pass any tests I throw at it. It seemingly has no bad sectors. I tested the drive with different software other than seatools to get a second opinion and it passed those tests too. In addition, I used to not be able read the drive at all and it would cause windows disk management, file explorer and sometimes it would cause the bios to hang on my computer. What should I do now? Should I still keep using it because it seems to be fine now or should I RMA it and get a repaired/refurbished drive since it is still under warranty?

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, since there is no way of knowing what was done inside the drive on repartioning. That said, *if it ain't broke, don't fix it*. One should *always* have backups of data, or, better, a complete disk image. If this drive has a valid image, then there is nothing to lose by using it until it actually fails.

Comment: I agree overall with the thinking above. But since under warranty, you might strongly consider getting a replacement drive.

Comment: Look at the SMART data stored on the drive

Comment: I did use software to check the smart data. The drive now shows up green and I don't see any yellow or red circles next to the different smart attributes indicating there is no problem. It seems to be in good health. Before I deleted all the partitions from and reformatted it under the Current Pending and reallocated sectors count it was yellow which indicated there were problems.

Answer (score 3):

The short version is that modern hard drives tend to not show their bad sectors anymore. When a physical defect on the disk surface is encountered, the drive will silently mark that specific area as unusable and instead write the incoming data to a reserve sector it keeps unused for precisely this occasion.

One of the functions of a disk format is to mark bad sectors as unusable, but how does this interplay with the reserve sectors mentioned above?

**By doing a full (non-quick) format, you force the drive to touch every sector on the disk. If there are bad sectors, they will be encountered and reallocated from the reserve at this time.**

The hard drive keeps a count of how many reallocated sectors it's used up. Windows provides no tools that can display all this data, but something like [HDTune](http://www.hdtune.com/) can surface this information. I'd be willing to bet that a look at the "health" tab will show your `Reallocated Sectors` count is either in the yellow or the red.

If this is the case, ***yes*** - RMA or replace the drive.

Comment: Good answer. I've never used HDTune, but for a quick GUI for SMART information I've found [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/) to be simple enough.

Comment: I used Crystal Disk Info and similar software and the drive now shows up green and I don't see any yellow or red circles next to the different smart attributes. It seems to be in good health. Before I deleted all the partitions from and reformatted it the Current Pending and reallocated sectors count showed up as yellow.

Comment: I used a program called g smart control to get information on the drive too. I highly recommend it it is a great program that tells you a lot of really detailed information about Hard Drives and Solid State Drives. I think it is way more useful than HD Tune or Crystal Disk Info. When I click on the drive that I am having issues with using Using G Smart and go to the statistics and the errors logs tab they tell me that there are lots of unrecoverable errors on the drive. When I go to the Attributes tab none of the SMART attributes are highlighted either.

Comment: That's highly irregular - there's no reason for the reallocated sectors count to ever go down. The error log telling you that there are unrecoverable errors though is a huge flashing red flag. This drive is *weird* and possibly broken in a strange way.. don't trust your data to it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I agree with you karu I was thinking that but I just wanted to get a second opinion about what to do with the drive. I guess I will just RMA the drive just to be safe. Any idea why something like this would happen?

Comment: Unfortunately I can only speculate. Firmware problem, maybe?